# C#/SQLCE CREATE TABLE programmatically (Auto increment + Primary key)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create a table in a SQL CE database programmatically.
Currently, I am using the following query - though I am getting an error;

```
string command = @"CREATE TABLE CONNECTION(" +
                  "connection_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                  "host NVARCHAR(255), port INT, key NVARCHAR(50), " +
                  "last_used NVARCHAR(15));";
```

The error I am getting is:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1, Token line offset = 104, Token in error = key ]

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am used to MySQL and the queries are slightly different.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173393(v=sql.90).aspx have a look at this @JW point is right add[] brackets to key.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try enclosing `key` in a brackets

```
string command = @"CREATE TABLE CONNECTION(" +
                        "connection_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                        "host NVARCHAR(255), port INT, [key] NVARCHAR(50), " +
                        "last_used NVARCHAR(15));";
```

- [Reserved Words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258313%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, pick another name for the column or you'll have to do this forever.

Comment: @DanBracuk I agree! to avoid future pain :D